# Как выводить текст с произвольной установкой каретки в linux?

Tags: курсор, вывод, консоль, c++, linux

как выводить текст в произвольном месте консоли (терминала) linux?

Comment: используйте `Ncurses`.

Comment: Смотрите библиотеку ncurses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значит так, есть два пути:

1. Это использовать [терминальные коды](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes)
2. Так как чаще всего эта адова задача возникает во время попытки создать интерфейс для терминала, то можно воспользоваться неплохой свободной библиотекой [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)(офф сайт [здесь](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html))

Второй вариант предпочтительнее, позволяет легко переносить приложение и удобнее в использование.

Comment: установил библиотеку ncurses-dev, подключил заголовок. При компиляции (пишу в qt creator'e) получаю ругань на все функции из этой библиотеки:
    error: undefined reference to `initscr' и т.п.
хотя физически это функция доступна.

Comment: А либы в проектном файле прописал?

LIBS += -L/usr/lib64/ncurses6 -lncurses<br>
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/ncurses6/ncurses
DEPENDPATH += /usr/include/ncurses6/ncurses

Comment: действительно библиотек не нашел только заголовки установились. про ncurses почитал это то что нужно. спасибо. дальше я сам